# Show that a metric space is complete.

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I have the following metric space:

$(M,\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert_2 ), M=\{(x,\frac{1}{x})\mid x\in(0,\infty)\}$

I need to show that it is complete, therefore showing that each cauchy sequence converges is sufficient.

So let $(x_{n},y_{n})$ Be a cauchy sequence.

$\forall \varepsilon >0 $ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m,n>N$ we have $d((x_{n},y_{n}),(x_{m},y_{m}))<\varepsilon.$

Denote $(x_{n},y_{n})=(x_{1},\frac{1}{x_{1}})$ and $(x_{m},y_{m})=(x_{2},\frac{1}{x_{2}})$

now $d((x_{n},y_{n}),(x_{m},y_{m}))<\varepsilon\iff(\sum\left|x_{1}-x_{2}\right|^{2}+\left|y_{1}-y_{2}\right|^{2})^{1/2}<\varepsilon$

How should I proceed, how can I formally show that it converges?

Comment: Why bother with $y$ variables?  All elements in $M$ are of the form $(x, \frac 1x)$ so if $\{W_n}; W_k \in M$ is your cauchy sequence each $W_n$ is of the form $(x_n, \frac 1{x_n})$ so the cauchy sequence is $(x_n, \frac 1{x_n})$.  ... Forget the $y$s....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

The metric space is a subspace from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ which is complete with $\parallel\cdot\parallel_{2}$, so it is sufficient to prove thar $M$ is closed.

In order to prove it, say that $\lbrace (x_{n}, \frac{1}{x_{n}})\rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $M$ such that it converges to an arbitrary point $(x, y)$. To be $M$ closed means that that limit lies into $M$ for that arbitrary sequence. It's a matter for seeing that $x>0$ since $\lbrace x_{n}\rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a positive sequence converging to $x$.

On the other hand, the sequence $\lbrace \frac{1}{x_{n}}\rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $\frac{1}{x}$ as a result for $\lbrace x_{n}\rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converging to $x$. By limit's uniqueness $y=\frac{1}{x}$. So indeed the arbitrary sequence in $M$ converges in $M$. Hence $M$ is closed.

If a sequence in $M$ is a Cauchy sequence, then it converges in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, since $M$ is closed, that limit lies in $M$ which means that $M$ is a complete metric space.

Answer (score 0):

If $(x_n, \frac{1}{x_n})$ is convergent in $(M, \|\cdot\|_2)$ then $x_n$ converges in $((0,\infty), |\cdot|).$ Let $\hat{x}$ be the limit of $x_n$. Show that $(x_n, \frac{1}{x_n})$ converges to $(\hat{x}, \frac{1}{\hat{x}})$ in $M.$